# How to use a host IP from a container?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

In a container running with host networking option it is possible to use a host network interface and its IP from the container and contact external network *from* this interface and IP. So if a host has several IPs configured, the container can choose which one it uses.

Can I have a similar setup with Kubernetes and let a container use an host IP ?

NB: I need the process to contact an external service *from* specific IPs, I dont necessarily need those IPs to be assigned to a container from an external view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hostNetwork=true` in pod specification exposes host network to the pod, and container can access network interfaces:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lookup
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: lookup
      image: sbusso/lookup_ips:latest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 9000
```

To test it: `kubectl port-forward lookup 9000` and then go to http://127.0.0.1:9000/ and get network interfaces details:

```
lo
- 127.0.0.1/8
- ::1/128
eth0
- 10.0.2.15/24
- fe80::a00:27ff:fea1:6e61/64
eth1
- 192.168.99.101/24
- fe80::a00:27ff:fe77:d179/64
```

Note this option is not recommended in Kubernetes good practices: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#services

Comment: Hi Stéphane, thanks, your answer was exactly what I was looking for (make a tcpdump inside a pod). But I don't understand because I thought that the pods need capabilities for that. With podman I use `--net=host --privileged` (the `--privileged` is overkill in this example). I can see that `.spec.hostNetwork` == `--net=host` but I don't see the equivalent of `--privileged` (edit with docker I don't need the `--privileged`)

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in [Egress IP adress selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943950/egress-ip-adress-selection/51944171) :

> One of the things that could help you solve it is Istio Egress Gateway so I suggest you look into it.
>
> Otherwise, it is still dependent on particular platform and way to deploy your cluster. For example on AWS you can make sure your egress traffic always leaves from predefined, known set of IPs by using instances with Elastic IPs assigned to forward your traffic (be it regular EC2s or AWS NAT Gateways). Even with Egress above, you need some way to define a fixed IP for this, so AWS ElasticIP (or equivalent) is a must.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea look interesting and then I look further about Egress Gateway. Apart of blocking the traffic to external services, I didnt see how to handle IPs from a container, or change the TCP request IP on request. It will also bring constraints as it needs to configure all external IPs and here we may have changing IPs. Host IPs are statically attached to the hosts and I dont plan to use AWS.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give this a shot. I hope i understand your question.  You only need to connect to an external ip from inside a pod/container.

We implemented this by creating a kubernetes service without a selector.

```
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: your-external-system
```

Followed by creating an Endpoint Object with the same name as your service.

```
kind: Endpoints 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata: 
  name: your-external-system
  subsets: 
    - addresses: 
       - ip: 192.168.0.1 
       ports: 
       - port: 3306
```

Finally in your pod, you can simply refer to the service name in this case (your-external-system)

Comment: Not to an external IP but *from* an host IP as a source IP.

Comment: Oh you dont have to do anything.  If the service your pod wants to communicate with is outside the cluster, the service will see the hostIp from where your pod is running.  I knew this because one of our system is using ip filtering to allow only certain hosts to connect to it. All we did was add all the kubernetes host Ips to the whitelist.

Comment: I need the container to choose its IP.

Comment: You can configure hostNetwork=true in your pod.  It is similar to docker --network host.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That is the option I figured out too and doing so tests